# which http code should I choose when jwt token expired

Tags: http, oauth-2.0

I am verifying the jwt token right now, when user did not pass the token, I could return the http like this:

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("User is not authenticated");
```

but when the token expired, which code should I choose to return? I am consider using 403, but it looks like the token is valid but did not have access right to specify resouce. How to tell the client the token is expired? or should I define a specify code like 425 to indicate? it looks like ugly or conflict with the standard.

Comment: This is opinionated question. I think the Microsoft-introduced unofficial code 440 (Login Time-out) fit you the most. You may check out Wikipedia for more of the unofficial codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors

Comment: @KoalaYeung It's not opinionated - 401 is the right answer.